# How to enable Full-text Indexing in SQL Server 2005 Express?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, full-text-search

I am trying to enable Full-text indexing in SQL Server 2005 Express. I am running this on my laptop with Vista Ultimate.

I understand that the standard version of SQL Server Express does not have full-text indexing. I have already downloaded and installed "Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Express Edition with Advanced Services Service Pack 2" ([download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=5B5528B9-13E1-4DB9-A3FC-82116D598C3D&displaylang=en)).

I have also ensured that both the "SQL Server (instance)" and "SQL Server FullText Search (instance)" services are running on the same account which is "Network Service".

I have also selected the option to "Use full-text indexing" in the Database Properties > Files area.

I can run the sql query "SELECT fulltextserviceproperty('IsFulltextInstalled');" and return 1.

The problem I am having is that when I have my table open in design view and select "Manage FullText Index"; the full-text index window displays the message...

> "Creation of the full-text index is not available. Check that you have the correct permissions or that full-text catalogs are defined."

Any ideas on what to check or where to go next?

Comment: Try this: [http://www.wherecanibuyit.co.uk/ASP/full-text-search.html](http://www.wherecanibuyit.co.uk/ASP/full-text-search.html) If that doesn't work, I'd use Lucene.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
sp_fulltext_database 'enable'

CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG [myFullText]
WITH ACCENT_SENSITIVITY = ON

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].[tblName] KEY INDEX [PK_something] ON [myFullText] WITH CHANGE_TRACKING AUTO
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].[otherTable] ADD ([Text])
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].[teyOtherTable] ENABLE
```

Answer (score 2):

All I needed to get full-text indexing to work was the...

> CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG [myFullText] WITH ACCENT_SENSITIVITY = ON

After that I could run a CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX query or use the Manage FullText Index in MSSQL Management Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Use sql server management studio.

Login as admin to your windows account.

Then select database and right click on database in sql server management studio and select Define Full Text Index and you are guided throughout the process by management studio.