# Improve text Search in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to improve text search in sql without using like '%%' expression ,and make search faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haneen,

The link will show you what you need to do.  Ultimately you need to add Full-Text indexes as Ziesemer pointed out.  If you are wanting to query documents make sure to install the appropriate iFilters (PDF, Office Docs, etc).

Please see issues I ran into [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690921/sql-server-pdf-full-text-search-not-working-on-filestream-pdf-file) with PDF searches using full-text indexing(hopefully this will save you some time if you plan on searching files)

--S

Answer (score 3):

Use SQL Server's [Full-Text Search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx) feature:

> In contrast to full-text search, the LIKE Transact-SQL predicate works
>   on character patterns only. Also, you cannot use the LIKE predicate to
>   query formatted binary data. Furthermore, a LIKE query against a large
>   amount of unstructured text data is much slower than an equivalent
>   full-text query against the same data. A LIKE query against millions
>   of rows of text data can take minutes to return; whereas a full-text
>   query can take only seconds or less against the same data, depending
>   on the number of rows that are returned.

See also: [How to enable Full-text Indexing in SQL Server 2005 Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052/how-to-enable-full-text-indexing-in-sql-server-2005-express)

Comment: Thank you so much for this information,I want to know how to do full-Text search ??